# Different stages are present in recruitment module in openerp, can we give any condition for these stages?

Tags: odoo

In Hr recruitment module, it has default 5 stages -initial qualification,first interview,second interview,contract proposed,contract signed,hired,refused.

I need to add a condition in contract proposed, if the condition is true he can jump into next stage. same like in contract signed.

How can i write a condition through interface or xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by implementing workflow into hr recruitment object.